# How to create a Database Scoped Credential to a Github repo or file?

Tags: github, azure-sql-database

I'd like to add an [External Data Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-create-an-external-data-source-for-bulk-operations-retrieving-data-from-azure-blob-storage) to an Azure SQL database. This requires a [Database Scoped Credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to be created.

Is it possible to create both of these things to connect to a Github repo/file?

Answer (score 1):

You can think about to using Azure Data Studio. Azure Data Studio is a cross-platform database tool for data professionals using the Microsoft family of on-premises and cloud data platforms on Windows, MacOS, and Linux.

[Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15) supports Git for version/source control. Please reference [Using source control in Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/source-control?view=sql-server-ver15).

Reference tutorial:: [Using Azure Data Studio with Git](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/using-azure-data-studio-with-git)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm. Interesting, but not quite the use case I had in mind. I already use VS Code with the MS SQL extension to run DB queries. Since my VS Code instance is tied to my Github repo, the functionality showed in the (great) tutorial, I already have. 

I'm rather asking if its possible to add a Github repo directly to a database as an External Data Source. This would allow me to run import scripts directly from my VCS, something quite different than what is shown in the tutorial.

Thank you

Comment: @SeaDude You're welcome. but from the document, External Data Source seems like do not support GitHub repo as the source.

Comment: I can not find any Azure documents to prove this, just according my experience, it's impossible to add the Github as the External Data Source. Can you please accept(mark) it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.